# Docker conatiner: Get passed environment varaible in tomcat spring mvc application

Tags: tomcat, docker, environment-variables

I am trying to deploy a SpringMVC application within a Docker container on top to tomcat8.

My problem is This SpringMVC application receive parameters using following code

```
String username = System.getProperty("db.username");
String password = System.getProperty("db.password");
```

I am running Docker container with the following command

```
docker run -e "db.username=root" -e "db.password=123" -v /home/ubuntu/code:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps -i -t -p 80:8080 tomcat
```

It starts the tomcat conatiner and try to deploy the application, but it does not work and throw application specifc errors username is empty and password is empty.

`System.getProperty` is not able to receive the passed `environment varaibles`.

**Important:** Please note I cannot change the code, I can only modify the docker related things.

**I think there should be a way to transform passed environment variables into Java property (in order for System.getProperties to work)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with the following command, but I will still wait for a better answer to accept.

```
docker run -v /home/ubuntu/code:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps -e JAVA_OPTS="-Ddb.username=root -Ddb.password=abc123" -it -p 80:8080 tomcat
```

In above command I am trying to run a tomcat container, I have mounted host directory onto container's tomcat webapps directory.

Then I am passing an environment variable `JAVA_OPTS` which will set Java properties that I will read in my Java code using `System.getProperty("db.username")`